# What is the correct indexing syntax for Rcpp NumericVector types?

Tags: c++, rcpp

I've built a process that will build a similarity matrix of dice-sorenson coefficients using R, but with the loops that are needed it naturally runs very slow. I'm trying to implement the solution using Rcpp, but am completely stuck with referencing vector indicies with the c++ code, and it doesn't help that I haven't worked with c++ in almost 7 years. The intended behavior for the code below is to take two R vectors of varying length (on average around 5-7 elements) which possess the values to be compared, and compute the numerator of the dice coefficient as an integer. The vectors will be filled with floating point values (342.02; 551.54; etc).  I'm getting a compile error that the "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector." I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743896/subscripted-value-is-not-an-array-pointer-or-vector-c) answer, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378980/indexing-slice-from-3d-rcpp-numericvector/23379025#23379025) answer, the Rcpp docs, and cplusplus.com for any help with the matter, but I think I just need someone to point out the obvious thing that I'm clearly missing. See code below . . .

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>

// [[Rcpp::export(name = "diceNumcpp")]]
int diceNum(NumericVector iso1, NumericVector iso2){

  NumericVector is1 = clone(iso1);
  NumericVector is2 = clone(iso2);
  int n = 0;
  int m = 0;
  int match = 0;

  while (is1[n]!=0){      //issue occurs with 'n' reference
    if (is2[m]==0){       //and again here with 'm' reference
      n++;
      m=0;
    }
    if (is1[n]!=0 && is2[m]!=0){  //same issue here with this line and the next
      if (abs(is1[n]-is2[m])/is2[m]<0.01){
        match++;
      }
      m++;
    }
  }
  return match;
}
```

Any help, or critiques of my terrible c++, will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

EDIT:

Here's some sample data.

R code:

```
iso1 <- c(595.06, 423.02, 321.06)
iso2 <- c(425.01, 321.06)
iso3 <- c(1476, 382.01)
```

Expected output between iso1 and iso2 = 2, Expected output between iso1 and iso3 = 2, and Expected output between iso2 and iso3 = 0

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0
```

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me.  Can you post a sample input data set?  I.e. for `diceNumcpp(1:4, 2:5)` I get 13 but I have no idea if that is meaningful.

Comment: Now, for whatever reason, it compiles. However when I run the same function with the same data I get different answers. I'm using iso1 and iso2 sample data above, but get 19, 2, and 22, and not in any particular order.

Comment: You may want to take the vector length into consideration. You are overrunnig the vectors.  Nothing guarantees '0' at or after the end.

Comment: Would is_na() be the right method in this case, rather than is1[n]==0? I understood that an empty element of a numeric vector of length n would equal 0. Ex. A vector with 5 elements but only two contain values, the remaining three contain 0s.

Comment: No, you may want to go back to some basic programming texts.  Here you have `NumericVector` which, like STL vectors, gives you `size()`. That is all you need. (You could place an 'end of vector' marker, but than you a) loose a possible value from your range and b) use one more memory element and c) do not make the code any easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That part works, now the next part.